# How to use nft.storage library in Angular 11 project

Tags: angular, nft

I have an Angular project in which I'm trying to use [nft.storage library](https://nft.storage/#docs). But I'm getting the following errors in Angular Cli:

```
Error: ./node_modules/nft.storage/src/platform.web.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ipfs-car/blockstore/memory' in '/home/newsha/Newsha/sonido-project/Sonido-front/node_modules/nft.storage/src'

Error: ./node_modules/nft.storage/src/lib.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ipfs-car/pack' in '/home/newsha/Newsha/sonido-project/Sonido-front/node_modules/nft.storage/src'

Error: ./node_modules/nft.storage/src/token.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ipfs-car/pack' in '/home/newsha/Newsha/sonido-project/Sonido-front/node_modules/nft.storage/src'
```

I installed the package using npm and then imported it in the project like this:

```
import { NFTStorage, File } from 'nft.storage'
import { pack } from 'ipfs-car/pack';

const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY'
const client = new NFTStorage({ token: apiKey })
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me instead of using

```
import { NFTStorage, File } from 'nft.storage';
```

use

```
import { NFTStorage, File } from 'nft.storage/dist/bundle.esm.min.js';
```

Ref: https://github.com/nftstorage/nft.storage/issues/876